# How to toggle entire group with react and d3 grouped and stacked bar chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a created a react + d3 stacked and grouped bar chart, the problem is that when I want to toggle each group by clicking on the label it doesn't work, I did something like:

```js
svg
  .select(".x-axis")
  .selectAll(".tick")
  .on("click", (e) => {
    const filteredD = data.map((d) => {
      return {
        name: d.name,
        Affiliate: d.name === e ? null : d.Affiliate,
        Social: d.name === e ? null : d.Social,
        Media: d.name === e ? null : d.Media
      };
    });
    setData(filteredD);
  });
```

it should work like this image:

[image]

you can check the full code and demo in [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-waterfall-jjel7?file=/src/StackedBarGraph.js)

any help to make it work will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-fast-e5msv?file=/src/StackedBarGraph.js)

```
const filteredD = data.map((d, index) => {
      if (d.name === e && !d.Affiliate) {
        return datasets[index];
      }
      return {
        name: d.name,
        type: d.type,
        Affiliate: d.name === e ? null : d.Affiliate,
        Social: d.name === e ? null : d.Social,
        Media: d.name === e ? null : d.Media
      };
    });
```

What I did:

1. Added an if statement triggered by !d.Affiliate;
2. Once the execution enters the if statement it just returns the initial data from props.datasets based on map()'s current index;